# JQuery Validation Date on dynamically created form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I want to validate a form that is dynamically generated. If I enter 123 in the form, it always returns true. Here is the code where I dynamically create the form:

```
//create dummy form so we can validate
$(".clearfix").append('<form action="#" id="dummyform" method="POST">');
$("#dummyform").append('<input type="text" name="dummyelement" class="date form-control" id="dummyelement"/>');

$('#dummyform').validate({
       ignore: [],
       rules:{
          dummyelement:{
               required: true,
               date: true

           }
       }
   });
```

I input 123, then call:

```
$('#dummyelement').valid()
```

this always returns true, for any input unless the input is empty. Can anyone elaborate why the date validation is not occuring?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the jQuery Validate plugin thinks `"123"` is a valid value for the `date` rule.  Conversely, enter `"abc"` and it's not valid.

In other words, you are doing nothing wrong, and should report this as a bug to the developer on [his GitHub page](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues).  Include the jsFiddle below inside your bug report.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ls3kqfu6/**

BTW, you do not need to use `class="date"` along with `date: true`... that is a redundant declaration of the rule.